# Energy after inverting voltage?

Tags: batteries

Here’s the real dumb question:
If my battery is 24v and 40Ah which makes 960 Watts. 
Now if i attach an invertor of 24v~230v how do i recalculate energy? Is it 230v X 40Ah or 24v X 40Ah ?

Answer (score 3):

24v times 40Ah makes 960 WattHours (Wh), not 960 Watts.

If you ran this through a perfect inverter, you would get 960Wh out.

To do the sums in my head, I'm going to call it 240v, so 960Wh would come out at 4Ah (slightly more Ah at 230v).

That's for a perfect inverter. In practice, you'll see a useful output of (probably) 80% to 90% of that, with the rest lost as heat in the inverter.

Answer (score 0):

It would be the battery voltage and the current that is pulled from its terminals. So Ah of the battery divided by the amps measured at the + terminal will give the estimate runtime (in hours).